# Text keyboard for a number in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've an input type element within a modal in my Ionic App:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)] = "price" placeholder="Inserisci i crediti" type="number" text-center></ion-input>
```

As you can see the type is "number", but the keyboard displayed in the iOs device is the standard text one; why? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [properties of ion-input](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#properties) you need to give it an inputmode.

> **inputmode**
>
> **Description**
>
> A hint to the browser for which keyboard to display.
> Possible values: "none", "text", "tel", "url", "email", "numeric",
> "decimal", and "search".
>
> **Attribute**
>
> inputmode Type    "decimal" | "email" | "none" | "numeric" |
> "search" | "tel" | "text" | "url" | undefined

I think this should work:

```
<ion-input inputmode="numeric" [(ngModel)] = "price" placeholder="Inserisci i crediti" type="number" text-center></ion-input>
```